Counting conjugacy classes of completely reducible subgroups in general linear groups
Let $G = GL(n, q)$ be the general linear group over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ with $q$ elements, where $q$ is a power of a prime $p$. Let $m$ be a positive integer dividing $q-1$. Suppose $\mathcal{C}(G, C_m)$ is the set of $G$-conjugacy classes of the collection of subgroups of $G$ that are both completely reducible and isomorphic to the cyclic group $C_m$ of order $m$
Is there an explicit formula for the cardinality $|\mathcal{C}(G, C_m)|$ in terms of $n$, $m$, and $q$? For a fixed $n$, what is the asymptotic behavior of $|\mathcal{C}(G, C_m)|$ as $m$ tends to infinity among the divisors of $q-1$?

Rational canonical form seems relevant here. Also, all cyclic subgroups  of order $m$ are automatically completely reducible under your hypotheses.

I'm puzzled by the phrase "as $m$ tends to infinity among the divisors of $q-1$".

A generator of such a subgroup is diagonalizable, and the number of conjugates of the subgroup that it generates will depend on the distribution of its multiset of eigenvalues, so I would not expect there to be an explicit formula.

I’m voting to close this question because the pattern of behaviour across several questions from the same account resembles past offenders
